# Oracle/SQL - Removing undefined chars from string

Tags: string, oracle, replace

I currently have an assignemnt where i have to handle data from a lot of countries. My customer have given me a list of acceptable characters, lets call it:

'aber =*'

All other characters should just be changed to '_'.

I know the conversion for my country's specific chars (æøå), easily done with something like

```
select replace ('Ål', 'Å', 'AA') from dual;
```

But how would i go about removing all unwanted "noise" without splitting it up in char-by-char comparison?

For example "bear*2 = fear" should become "bear*_ = _ear" as 2 and f are not in the accepted list.

Comment: your bigger issue will probably be preventing these "bad chars" from getting back in the db after you do your conversions.  I'm guessing you have many sources of this data, which will reintroduce these chars very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle 10g and up. As one of the approaches, you can use regular expression function `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace('bear*2 = fear', '[^aber =*]', '_') as res
  from dual


res
------------------------------
bear*_ = _ear
```

[Find out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm#i1305521) more about `regexp_replace()` function.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, i wasnt aware that that function was available.